# Snape's moral character: violent?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

Snape was literally Voldemort's right-hand man. He ends as somewhat of a hero in the series. Despite having a desire to respect him, I always remember he must be quite the killer to supplant Bellatrix, Malfoy, and other Death Eaters. Did Snape kill a lot of people?

Comment: What makes you think Voldemort chooses his followers (much less those closest to him, if any can be said to be that at all) based on how many people they've killed? That wouldn't fit with his character at all, and it would also be a very daft way of recruiting lackeys.

Comment: Related: [Would Severus Snape be classified with ASPD?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58648/21267)